# Add multiple target contacts in advanced search

Tags: advanced-search

I'm looking to send a mailing out to a subset of our contacts - those that have a relationship 'member of' and then Target Contact ' Group 1, Group 8, Group 12 etc' I'm creating a Smart Group to do this but had hoped that I could add more than one value in the 'Target Contact' field before running the Search but apparently not. They appear to need to be done one at a time which is a very time-consuming process if there are say forty groups that need to go into the smart group. I tired comma separation but it didn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your using Adcanced search to build this

You could try adding your targets
' Group 1, Group 8, Group 12 etc'

Into just a standard static group.

Then Advanced search
group="new group"

Display results as- switch to related contacts "relationship type=member of"

Does that get you closer?

Answer (score 0):

Try the Search Builder, this should let you do the required set of sub-searches